# How to convert multiple lists to dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, parsing, csv, dictionary

```
['*a*', '*b*', '*c*', '*d*', '*f*','*g*']
['11', '22', '33', '44', '', '55']
['66', '77', '88', '', '99', '10']
['23', '24', 'sac', 'cfg', 'dfg', '']
```

need to put in dictionary as:

```
{a : ('11','66','23'),b : ('22','77','24'),c : ('33','88','sac'),d :('44','','cfg')}
```

The rows are read from a CSV file:

```
import csv
csvFile = csv.reader(open("sach.csv", "rb"))
for row in csvFile:
    print row
```

code which is tried shown above,
The output of row is shown above which has many lists.
please help me to put it in dictionary format as shown above.

Comment: In your dictionary, do you need the keys to be like, `a` ,`'a'`, or `'*a*'` ?

Answer (score 7):

Zip the rows:

```
with open("sach.csv", "rb") as csv_infile:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_infile)
    yourdict = {r[0].replace('*', ''): r[1:] for r in zip(*reader)}
```

The [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) does the pairing for you, by passing in the `reader` object with the `*` argument Python will loop over the CSV rows and pass each row as a separate argument to `zip()`.

Comment: @martineau: since the OP post on that point is not valid Python unless the `a`, `b`, etc. are local variables, I didn't want to touch on that part. It just wasn't clear if the asterisks were markup even. But thanks for fixing the missing `:`.

Comment: @Martijn: True, it's a little ambiguous what the keys of the resulting dictionary are, since they're not quoted in the desired result shown in the OP's question -- but in the lists shown which were read from the csv file, they are definitely strings with asterisks in them. Regardless, your answer is very clever.